# How can I build a powershell hash table with brackets characters in its properties

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, hashtable, powershell-7.3

I'm trying to web scrape some information from my corporate website, the problem is: both the username and password elements name the name of the fields have brackets in it.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Message "input e-mail and password"

$LoginUri = "It's an corporate intranet website, I can't show it"
$LoginPage = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -SessionVariable "TempSession"
$Auth_Token = $LoginPage.InputFields | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "Auth_Token"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

$AuthBody = @{
    user[name]      = $Creds.UserName
    user[password]  = $Creds.Password
    Auth_Token      = $AuthToken
    Submit      = "Login"
}

$LogonMethod = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -Body $AuthBody -WebSession $TempSession -Method Post
```

PowerShell response when I try to build the hashtable is:

```
PS C:\Users\diego> $AuthBody = @{
>>    user[name]    = $Creds.UserName
>>    user[password]    = $Creds.Password
>>    Auth_Token    = $AuthToken
>>    Submit        = "Login"
>> }
ParserError: 
Line |
   2 |      user[name]        = $Creds.UserName
     |          ~
     | Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
```

The elements are these:

```
<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="string text required" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Usuário" type="text" value="" name="user[name]" id="user_name">

<input autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" class="password required" required="required" aria-required="true" placeholder="Senha" type="password" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
```

I already tried to set the name of the element id in the properties of the hashtable, it worked when I used selenium webdriver (for chrome) and exported it to python, I'm really not used to python so I'm trying to avoid it.

How can I build this PowerShell hashtable with brackets on it? Is there a way to call the input field by its id?

Comment: Needs to be quoted. `'user[name]' = ...`

Comment: Slightly shorter: `$Auth_Token = $LoginPage.InputFields.Where{ $_.name -eq "Auth_Token" }.Value`

Comment: Shouldn't `-Body $Auth` be `-Body $AuthBody` instead?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, i can't believe is that simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @zett42, It's long on purpose, by corporate culture, we have to write the code in the most comprehensible way possible, people here understand pipes better.

Comment: @Darin, you're totally right.